# How to get a token from a Github user via login?

Tags: android, github

### Background

Suppose I want to search for some email addresses on Github using code (Kotlin/Java).

### The problem

I've succeeded doing it without any login token, but as I've read it's limited to just 10 queries per minute, and if I have a token from the user ([from login to Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit)), it adds 30 queries per minute.

To get information from Github without login, I use OKHTTP to reach this (found from [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users)):

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$email+in:EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE
```

And if I could use a token, it would probably be:

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$email+in:EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE&access_token=$TOKEN_HERE
```

But I don't get how to get this token from the user. I can find how to make one for myself, using the website itself.

### What I've found and tried

I asked Github about how it's done, but they showed me some [curl code](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow), which sadly I'm not familiar with and I have no idea how it's done there and how to convert it to Kotlin/Java. I tried to read for [alternatives](https://blog.overops.com/tutorial-how-to-implement-java-oauth-2-0-to-sign-in-with-github-and-google/?utm_content=buffer3ee2e&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer), but then I've found some missing information about how it's done (missing prior data that is required for the parameters). I don't even get if it's working by using a WebView or directly contacting the Github servers. If it's directly contacting the Github servers, doesn't it mean that I need to have userName&password EditTexts for the user?

This is the code I've seen on the tutorial:

```java
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    AuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(),
    httpTransport, jsonFactory,
    new GenericUrl("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"),
    new ClientParametersAuthentication( /* Client ID and Secret */ ),
    /* Client ID */
    "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize").build();

    TokenResponse tokenResponse = flow
    .newTokenRequest(code)
    .setScopes(Collections.singletonList("user:email"))
    .setRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    request.getHeaders().setAccept("application/json");
    }
    }).execute();
```

So, what's missing here is "Client ID and Secret" , "code", and the part that the user himself provides : the user-name and password to get the token.

### The questions

How do I get into the whole login process, and finally get a token to be used?

Should it use a WebView to offer the user with all options to login, or should I use my own UI to put userName&password?

Answer (score 0):

Github supports `OAuth 2.0` for authentication. You can setup your application on Github to enable this feature as per this [example](https://insomnia.rest/blog/oauth2-github-api/) and you can also use [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) to handle the authentication journey.

Comment: Can you please explain further? I don't understand how it's done for Android apps. That's why I asked it. Do I have to set something for the app on Github's website? Does it all happen on the WebView of the app or do I need to provide a UI for login myself? If what you suggest is to get the token for myself, this is not a solution, because as I've read the limits are per-token, so each user won't have those limits, but in total, for all users. What is the second link you've provided? Is it a sample of how it's done? It says I need to edit a configuration file. What should be filled for Github?